# Cannot completely scroll div Horizontally

Tags: html, css, scroll

**I am trying to create a horizontal slider for scrolling across all the images in the div of given width**

*Note: Earlier getting the same issue while vertically scrolling, but resolved it using an extra-wrapper div.
But similar is not working in horizontal scrolling.*

**HTML**:

[image]

**CSS**

```
#parent{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 800px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 4;
   border-radius: 12px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(162,207,242,0.17);
   overflow-x: auto;
   padding: 1.25rem;
}

#extra-wrapper{
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: no-wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
   min-width: 100%;
   gap: 0.25rem;
   max-width: unset;
}

#image{
   position: relative;
   width: 125px;
   height: 125px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background-color: #f6f6f6;
   transition: all 0.2s ease;
   padding: 0.25rem;
   z-index: 5;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(162,207,242,0.25);
}
```

---

#### Here is the problem

[image]

##### The first image that is leftmost scrollable in the div is at index 4 (*with black border for highlight*) and the first ones are not approachable.

It can be scrolled completely to right but not to the left.

Can pls someone explain, why it is so?

Comment: Just remove `justify-content: center;`. Check it [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/5vekgpfm/). You can also check this article [Centring flex items and allowing overflow scroll](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2021/04/centring-flex-items-and-allowing-overflow-scroll/) if you need to center images when their width is less than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the default setting for the scrolls, they can't be in the middle, use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `overflow-x: scroll;`